# What is the set of (probability) measures $P$ such that $\operatorname{D_{KL}}<\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, information-theory, density-function

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)$ be some measurable space and let $P$ be a (probability) measure on $\Omega$. For another (probability) measure $Q$ such that $P>>Q$ the Kullback-Leibler divergence is defined as

$$ \operatorname{D_{KL}}(Q||P) = \int \ln \frac{dQ}{dP} dQ,$$

provided that this integral is well defined. Now if we denote the set of all $Q$ such that this expression exists and is finite by $M_P$, that is

$$M_P := \{Q \in \mathcal{M}(\Omega,\mathcal{F})| P>>Q, \operatorname{D_{KL}}(Q||P) < \infty \},$$

then what can we say about this set? Are there some known necessary and sufficient conditions on the measures?

According to [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882347/how-is-the-kullback-leibler-distance-between-probability-measures-well-defined) it is e.g. not sufficient that there exists some measure $\mu$ that dominates both $P$ and $Q$.

Also, it would be interesting if we know something about the structure of $M_P$, for example, it should be convex: Since the function $x\ln \frac{x}{y}$ is convex in $x$, we would get $$Q,\hat{Q} \in M_P, \lambda \in [0,1] \implies \lambda Q + 1-\lambda \hat{Q} \in M_P.$$

Is there more we can say?
Could it be a vector space (if we extend in a sensible way the definition to measures in general)?

The only thing that I found out so far is that it is not necessarily closed:
One can consider measures $Q^n$ that converge in law to a point mass. Then of course the limit is not in $M_P$, but this comes more from the fact that it is not dominated anymore than from the actual quantity of interest here.